# ¿Cómo puedo descargar archivos con selenium Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

estoy intentando descargar algún fichero con selenium pero a la hora de descargar me salta la notificación de descarga. He configurado el chrome para que no me permita confirmación pero sigue saliendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A demás he utilizado código para modificarlo. Aquí os paso el código si se puede solucionar o ayudarme
En el @Before:

```
@Before
public void setUpTest() {
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting.popups",0)
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory","ruta de archivo");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",chromePrefs);
}
```

en el @Test:

```
@Test
public void descarga() {
//localiza la ruta
        File listaFiles = new File(downloadFile);//downloadFile -> es la ruta de la descarga
        File[] archivos = listaFiles.listaFiles();
        //ordenamos por orden, la ultima modificacion, así el ultimo sera el primero
        Array.sort(archivos, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified).reserved());
        //el primer elemento será el ultimo modificado
        File lastFile = file[0];
        
        WebELement firma = driver.findElement(By.id("continuarFimra"));
        String sourceLocation = firma.getAttribute("onclick");
        String ejecutarCMD = "cmd / c" + downloadFile +"\\+lastFile.getName() +" -P D: --no-check-certificate"+ sourceLocation;
        try {
            Process excec = Rutime.getRuntime().excec(ejecutarCMD);
            int exitVal = excec.waitFor();
            
        
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.out.println(e.toString);
        }

}
```

**se puede hacer una llamada que pueda quitar los permisos del navegador ?**

Answer (score -1):

Ya está solucionado, quien necesite alguna vez una descarga y quitar las notificaciones, este es el código:
Tenemos que usar el ChromeOptions para almacenar las variables, esto sirve que llama al driverChrome por detrás, quite las notificaciones y permita descargar sin más.

```
 @Before
    public void setUpTest() {
    HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//indicamos que la notificaciones se bloqueen
    chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_setting.values.notifications",2)
//indicamos que el navegador llame al directorio que hemos indicado
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory","ruta de archivo");
//usando el chromeOptions, para guardar los argumentos
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs",chromePrefs);
    options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("no-sandbox");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }
```

Comment: Las respuestas de solo código no resultan tan *completas* o fáciles de comprender... Podrías mencionar los cambios que hiciste para arreglarlo y alguna explicación. Para más información puedes leer [answer]. Ten en cuenta que se trata de que quien busque respuesta pueda *aprender* y *entender* por qué esto funciona, no solo copiar y pegar y ala, ya va.